# How to find specific string in array and print the array variable name jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to create a function to print the array variable name.

```
var myString = "Apple";
var myCategory = ["Mango","Apple","froot","others"]

found = $.grep( myCategory, function ( value, i) {
   return (value.indexOf( myString) >= 0);
});
alert(found);
```

output = "Apple" (its fine);

I want the array Variable name i.e "myCategory" if the string found in array.

Comment: that is not how code works, in general. what you want is to load your source code as a string and then analyze that to find what you're looking for ...

Comment: Its required to return the variable name and save to database. @ alebianco

Comment: I want the "myCategory" if the myString value found on same

Comment: It seems like what you want is to be able to search through a variable, which represents an array, who's name you don't know, and return the name of that variable if the array contains a search string. Understand that this is a very "odd" question. You should "never need to do that". Your explanation thus far of "it needs to be saved to the database" also suffers from the same oddity - "you should never need to store a variable's name to the database". I recommend providing a higher level description of what goal you're trying to achieve overall so you can get more help.

Answer (score 0):

Names of variables are indentifiers , and you cannot ask for an identifier what its name is.

If you want , you can create a new variable equal to the name of that indentifier

```
var output = myCategory; 

if(found === true){
   alert(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the namestring of a variable as far as I know. What you could do though, is place all the arrays into one object and return the propertyname of that array instead.

```
   var myString = "Apple",
        data = {
            "myCategory" : ["Mango","Apple","froot","others"],
            "othercategory" : ["Car", "Bike", "Boat"]
        },
        find = function find( str ) {
            return Object.keys(data).reduce(function( result, aryName ) {
                if (data[aryName].indexOf(str) !== -1) result = aryName;
                return result;
            }, false);
        };
    console.log(find(myString));
```